# how to Identify Authoritative name servers from a list of IP addresses

Tags: python, dns, reverse-dns

**say i have a list of IP addresses,what's the best way to identify if these servers are the authoritative name servers?i'm currently using python**

Comment: An authoritative Nameserver is a DNS Server that holds the actual DNS zone for a **particular domain**, so your question can't be answered (you need to provide the domain name)

Comment: thank you.i think i have the answers i need

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear - I'm assuming you mean the authoritive NS for the PTR record (.in-addr.arpa.)?

using the dnspython module from http://www.dnspython.org/ and a tip on converting the IP address into the in-addr.arpa format

```
import dns.resolver
resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver() 
for ipaddr in myIPAddrList:
  req = '.'.join(reversed(ipaddr.split("."))) + ".in-addr.arpa"
  ptr_rrs = resolver.query(req, "PTR") 
  for ptr_rr in ptr_rrs:
    ns_rrs = resolver.query(ptr_rr, "NS")
    for ns_rr in ns_rrs:
      print "%s is an NS record for the PTR record %s for IP Address %s" % (ns_rr, ptr_rr, ipaddr)
```